# Good resources for learning advanced OOP features in PHP 5?

Tags: php, oop

I'm familiar with advanced OOP features like `interfaces`, `abstractions`, `enums`, `generics`, `public , private , static` keywords, `exceptions`, etc from Java. However, I'd like to know how all these things translate to PHP.

Specifically I'd like one tutorial or website which goes through all the advanced OOP features of PHP which were added in PHP 5 (I'm mostly familiar with everything from PHP 4) and also things which aren't directly related to OOP like the `throw` keyword and the `try/catch` blocks. Any suggestions?

Comment: The php documentation is always a good spot; on php.net/oop you'll find a good introduction into the basics, but I think this is not what you're looking for. For try/catch behaviour have a look at php.net/exceptions ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a decent and free e-book called "[PHP 5 Power Programming](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/013147149X/downloads/013147149X_book.pdf)" (~5 MiB PDF) that I would recommend. It goes into the more advanced aspects of OOP in PHP and explains some common design patterns.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you haven't been there already, the php.net documentation is pretty good. [Here](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) is the section on PHP5's objects. There also is a section on [migrating from PHP4 to PHP5](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php).